# Subtracting a float from another float does not equal a float?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am coding with the unity scripting API but I don't think that changes anything.

I have a variable *playerMovementScript.rightWallX* that is a float and is equal to -20.84.

I then have this line of code:

```
Debug.Log(-21.24f == playerMovementScript.rightWallX - 0.4f);
```

It always prints false. I feel like I'm missing something obvious cause I'd like to think I'm not THAT new to coding. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Floating point is not as accurate as you think. You need to check if it is approximately the value you want

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Approximately.html

Answer (score 1):

Floating points not accurate. Use them only for fast calculations. If u want to compare 2 floats use if (Mathf.Approximately(floatA,floatB))

Comment: While your suggestion is spot on, the reasoning isn't quite right: floating point is very accurate. The problem is not accuracy, but the inability to represent most base-ten fraction numbers in base-two (binary) without infinite precision. This is because 0.1 in decimal is 0.001100110011... (repeats forever) in binary. However, 32-bit floats have only 24 significant bits (23 plus an implicit leading 1 bit), so 0.1d is represented as 1.10011001100110011001101*2^-3, with that final 1101 due to rounding. Thus multiplying by 10(decimal) results in a number slightly larger than 1.0.

Comment: (continuation of above) However, one in 16-million (24 bits) is pretty accurate and even fairly precise. The problem is there are tricks for dealing with the rounding, including, as you suggest, not doing *direct* comparisons between floats, and thus goes against our intuition.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it prints false is because you are using the == operator, which checks if 2 things are equal, therefore since you are doing `-21.24f == playerMovementScript.rightWallX - 0.4f`, the result is unequal and then it prints false. I am pretty sure you meant =, but we all make mistakes.

Comment: The second part of your answer makes no sense, you cannot assign something to a value.